# $query conflicting with other queries in the same page

Tags: wp-query, loop

This is my front page:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Front Page
 *
 * @package bbPress
 * @subpackage Theme
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary">
      <div id="content" role="main">

        <div class="articles">
        <h2><?php echo __( 'Recent Articles', 'twentyeleven' ) ?></h2>
          <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'front-page' ); ?>

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

          <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        </div>

        <div class="articles">
          <h2><?php echo __( 'Upcoming Events', 'twentyeleven' ) ?></h2>
          <?php echo do_shortcode('
            [events_list limit="3"]
              <article class="hentry">
                <div class="entry-left">
                  #_EVENTIMAGE{60,60}
                </div>
                <div class="entry-right">
                  <h3>#_EVENTLINK</h3>
                  <p class="e-p">#_CUSTOMEXCERPT</p>
                </div>
              </article>
            [/events_list]
          '); ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->

        <div class="articles recent-forum-topics">
          <h2><?php echo __( 'Recent Forum Topics', 'twentyeleven' ) ?></h2>
          <?php // Create and run custom loop
              $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
              $custom_posts->query('post_type=topic&posts_per_page=7');
              while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
          ?>  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="entry-left">
                  <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div><!-- .entry-header -->
              </article>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </div>

        <div class="articles">
          <h2><?php echo __( 'Taiwan News', 'twentyeleven' ) ?></h2>
          <div class="entry-left">
            <?php
              include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php'); // path to include script
              $feed = fetch_rss('http://www.taiwansnews.net/index.php/rss/0dd057261bcc461b'); // specify feed url
              $items = array_slice($feed->items, 0, 4); // specify first and last item
            ?>

            <?php if (!empty($items)) : ?>
            <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>

              <article class="hentry hentry-news">
                  <h3><a href="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>"><?php echo $item['title']; ?></a></h3>
              </article>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #content -->

        <div class="articles">
          <h2><?php echo __( 'Events Calendar', 'twentyeleven' ) ?></h2>
          <div class="entry-left">
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[events_calendar long_events=0 ]'); ?>
          </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #content -->

        <div class="articles">
          <h2><?php echo __( 'Weather Forecast', 'twentyeleven' ) ?></h2>
          <div class="weather-forecast-wrapper">
            <div class="entry-left">
              <?php echo do_shortcode('[forecast location="Taipei, Taiwan" caption="Weather for Taipei" measurement="C" todaylabel="Today" datelabel="date("m/d/Y")" highlow="%%high%%°/%%low%%°" numdays="3" iconset="Incredible" class="weather-forecast" cache="true" width="100%"]'); ?>
            </div><!-- #content -->
          </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #content -->

        <div class="articles">
        <h2><?php echo __( 'My Articles', 'twentyeleven' ) ?></h2>
        <?php // Create and run custom loop
            global $tax_selection; // use your variable
            $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
            $custom_posts->query( array( 
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                'posts_per_page' => 5, 
                'category__in' => $tax_selection['categories'],
            ) );
            while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
        ?>  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
              <div class="entry-left">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
              </div><!-- .entry-header -->
            </article>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have this in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'do_user_post_selection' );

function do_user_post_selection( $query ) {

    if( !is_home() || !is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && ( 'nav_menu_item' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) )
        return; 
    if( 1 < did_action('wp') )
        return;
    global $current_user;

    $tax_selection = get_user_option( 'taxonomy_selection', $current_user->ID );

    if( empty( $tax_selection ) )
        return;

    if( isset( $tax_selection['categories'] ) && ( is_array( $tax_selection['categories'] ) ) && ( !empty( $tax_selection['categories'] ) ) ) 
        $query->set( 'category__in', $tax_selection['categories'] );
    if( isset( $tax_selection['post_tag'] ) && ( is_array( $tax_selection['post_tag'] ) ) && ( !empty( $tax_selection['post_tag'] ) ) ) 
        $query->set( 'tag__in', $tax_selection['post_tag'] );

    return;
}
```

This is making `Recent Forum Topics` to disappear.

How to only apply the `$tax_selection;` to My Articles without breaking the other posts?

Comment: Your taxonomy query in your front page code has a `category__in` parameter. Why are you also trying to set it with a hook on `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Oh, I commented `$query->set` before and was using using that `category__in`, but for some reason, it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pre_get_posts( $query ){
    if(isset($query->getpostlist) && $query->getpostlist) {
        add_filter( 'posts_fields', 'postsetupFields', 20);    
    } else {
        remove_filter( 'posts_fields', 'postsetupFields', 20); 
    }
return $query;
}

function postsetupFields( $fields ){
    global $wpdb;
    $fields = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
    return $fields;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'postsetupFields');
```

Comment: So which custom loop will this code affect?

Comment: Please add a description as well as simply post code. What does this do? And why name a callback the same as the hook? That looks like bad for to me.

Comment: Also, this code produces a fatal error and please explain `$query->getpostlist`.